# Passing a variable to a dynamic dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have 2 dropdownlists, one is State and the second is City.  I am trying to create it so, when a user clicks the State, the second dropdownlist is populated with City names from a datatable.

Here is the code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<%--<cc2:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDown1" runat="server"> </cc2:CascadingDropDown>--%>
<h1>Live Event Search Engine</h1><br />
State: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="ST_Code" DataValueField="ST_Code" /><asp:SqlDataSource
    ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnection %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ST_Code] FROM [State]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
City:  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="RS_City" DataValueField="RS_City" /><asp:SqlDataSource
    ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnection %>"
    SelectCommand="web_PublicProgramListbyState" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
<SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="State" SessionField="ST_Code" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
       <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

</asp:Content>
```

and the code behind is

```
Public Sub ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlState.SelectedIndexChanged
        Me.ddlCity.Items.Clear()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("web_PublicProgramListbyState", New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbConnection")))
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "@State")
        da.Dispose()
        Me.ddlCity.DataSource = ds.Tables("Products")
        Me.ddlCity.DataTextField = "ProductName"
        Me.ddlCity.DataValueField = "ProductID"
        Me.ddlCity.DataBind()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are asking about?  Is there an error, does this not work?

Comment: @Brian, well it doesn't work. The Variable from the "State" doesn't get passed to "City", and the City Dropdownlist doesn't load.  I just get an Error.

Comment: Code shows binding of programs and not cities?  Anyway, posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to bring a dataset into this when you already have a SqlDataSource defined.  Just modify the parameters of the SqlDataSource and re-bind:

```
Public Sub ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(...)
    SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Clear()
    SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add(New Parameter("@State", DbType.String, ddlState.SelectedValue))
    ddlCity.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Edit: Or you can use a ControlParameter referencing ddlState.SelectedValue in SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters as mentioned in another answer.  Only trick there is you have to manage your default values carefully so ddlCity only binds when you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

I would change it to a control param and just call the databind.  No need to do the fill yourself.

```
 <asp:ControlParameter Name="State" ControlID="ddlState" Type="String" />
```

and then in the select event just call:

```
Me.ddlCity.DataBind()
```

Or if you want to remove the codebehind all together put it in an update panel with a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged event writes the session variable.  This is required.